# Make granting extended permission optional for an application?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm developing a Facebook canvas application. One of the features in this application will be posting to the user's stream when they perform certain actions, i.e. logging into the app ("User X is now playing at App Y!"), purchasing a virtual product ("User X has just purchased Product Y on App Z!") etc. To do this, I need the "publish_stream" extended permission. However; I want this to be optional.

Previously, I used the following method from Facebook's old REST API:

`$user = $facebook->require_login('email,publish_stream');`

But this denies access to the application if the user doesn't grant the "publish_stream" permission. The problem being, my manager wants this to be optional; if they don't have the permission then don't post to the stream.

Is it possible to make granting extended permissions optional? Or is it black-and-white, "if you don't grant us this extended permission then you can't play"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via the new Javascript SDK:

```
FB.login([callback_function], { perms: 'email,publish_stream' });
```

More info here: [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login)

Be aware, however, that FB strongly frowns upon the kind of "X is playing Y" publishing you're after: [Facebook Stream Stories](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/stream)

Comment: I would advise against it too, but that's the joys of working as a web developer for a marketing agency where it's their way or the highway!